# Bidirectional Bar Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Thank you for your help in advance. I'm relatively new to R and I'm working on creating a bidirectional bar chart using ggplot2.

```
p3 <- ggplot(online_offline,aes(x=Year,y=Percentage, fill=Online_Offline))+ 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity")+
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-max(online_offline$Percentage), max(online_offline$Percentage), 10))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 15))+
coord_flip()
p3
```

That is the code i'm using and this is the result I'm getting. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ6Ta.jpg)

I would like it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYjrX.png). Could anyone please help me?

The data I am using is:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJa2h.png)

Comment: See the following on R Community https://community.rstudio.com/t/stack-order-of-geom-bar-reversing-order/36258

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Thank you for including your data, but screenshots require folks to retype it - can you paste a  `dput` or some variation in your original post?  Second, if you're plotting two percentages that sum to 100, why not use something like a [stacked barplot](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.html)?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you have to the change the sign of the values for one of your categories. This could be achieved e.g. by mapping `ifelse(on_off == "Online", Percentage, -Percentage)` on `y`. Additionally to set the range of your axis you have to use `limits` instead of `breaks`:

```r
online_offline <- structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 
                              2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L), Percentage = c(19.5, 
                                                                                        73.6, 19.3, 72.7, 21.8, 69.3, 26.1, 64.7, 28.6, 62.9, 61.4, 36.8
                              ), on_off = c("Online", "Offline", "Online", "Offline", "Online", 
                                            "Offline", "Online", "Offline", "Online", "Offline", "Online", 
                                            "Offline")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(online_offline,aes(x=Year, y = ifelse(on_off == "Online", Percentage, -Percentage), fill=on_off))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-max(online_offline$Percentage), max(online_offline$Percentage))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 15))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]